# Provide a geometrical interpretation of span vector

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

My question is about:
Find the conditions onto $b_1, b_2$, and $b_3$ such that the following system is consistent:

$2x_1 - 2x_2 = b_1$

$3x_1 + 3x_2 = b_2$

$4x_1 - 4x_2 = b_3$

Provide a geometrical interpretation of the result.

I already found the condition is $b_3 = 2b_1$
but I don't know how to provide a geometrical interpretation of this result.

Comment: Vectors 1 and 3 are collinear.